# ¿la sentencia sql en postgres, es necesario el prefijo "public"?

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, pdo

estoy trabajando con PHP y PDO conectandome a una base de datos de postgresql, tengo una duda, ya que esta pasando algo que no espero.

```
$pdo = new PDO('pgsql:dbname=db_pdo_postgresql; 
                            host=localhost;', 'juan_postgres', 'root');
        foreach($pdo->query('SELECT * from user') as $fila) {
            if($fila==null){
                echo "Vacio";

            }else{
                echo "<pre>";
                print_r($fila);
            }
        }
        $pdo = null;
```

Ese es el codigo, y el resultado es este.

```
Array
(
    [current_user] => juan_postgres
    [0] => juan_postgres
)
```

me devuelve practicamente el usuario. y si le cambio al query

```
SELEC * from public.user
```

Me devuelve.

```
Array
(
    [ID] => 1
    [0] => 1
    [name] => Laura
    [1] => Laura
)

    Array
    (
        [ID] => 2
        [0] => 2
        [name] => Juan
        [1] => Juan
    )
```

El caso, es que no quisiera que este agregando el prefijo public, en cada sentencia sql. ya que al cambiar de BD, tendria que modificar el SQL. y ese no seria el caso, para el uso de PDO.
gracias

Comment: Ya corregi el problema.

Comment: El asunto es que debes mencionar el esquema al cual pertenece la tabla de la base de datos a la cual estas conectando. (no siempre sera public, podria ser nombrado de otra manera)

Comment: @JuanL si ya corregiste el error, publica una respuesta describiendo la solución.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generalmente cuando te conectas a postgresql puedes acceder a cualquier tabla a la que el usuario con el que te has conectado tenga privilegios de acceso.

Ahora bien, **si dos tablas se llaman iguales**, como es el caso aquí, es lógico que deberías especificar mediante el `schema`, a cuál de ellas te quieres conectar. Lo que estaba ocurriendo en tu caso es que la consulta estaba trayendo los datos de la tabla de usuarios de postgresql.

Para evitar esas confusiones recomendaría que no llames a tus tablas con nombres que sean [**palabras reservadas**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.3/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html) de postgresql. Tal práctica, aparte de llevarte a confusiones como la actual, podría poner en riesgo los datos, por ejemplo, exponiendo las credenciales de acceso de los usuarios de la base de datos en sí, o permitiendo modificar la clave de acceso del administrador de la base de datos o de un usuario con privilegios de edición. Como comprenderás, esto podría llevar a situaciones muy delicadas debido a una confusión entre las tabla `users` de la base de datos misma y una posible tabla <s>`users`</s>  que sería parte de una aplicación en concreto.

Si de todos modos, por algún motivo dos tablas tienen que llamarse iguales y se encuentran en dos `schema` distintos, tú puedes establecer el `schema` por defecto mediante [`search_path`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-set.html). De ese modo, no te verás obligado a escribir el `schema` en cada consulta.

Supongamos el siguiente escenario:

### ▸ En Postgresql

```
schema_app1
    tabla1
    tabla2

schema_app2
    tabla1
    tabla2
```

### ▸ En una aplicación `app1`

Si cuando conectes a PDO en la `app1` haces esto:

```
$pdo->exec('SET search_path TO schema_app1');
```

Y luego haces:

```
SELECT * FROM tabla1;
```

Estarás haciendo referencia a la `tabla1` de `schema_app1`. O sea: `schema_app1.tabla1`.

### ▸ En una aplicación `app2`

Si cuando conectes a PDO en la `app2` haces esto:

```
$pdo->exec('SET search_path TO schema_app2');
```

Y luego haces:

```
SELECT * FROM tabla1;
```

Estarás haciendo referencia a la `tabla1` de `schema_app2`. O sea, es como si hicieras: `schema_app2.tabla1`.